# Is this suffeicent to conclude it is not a subgroup

Tags: group-theory

If I was wondering if $G=\{1,(123),(231),(124),(142)\}$ was a subgroup of $S_{4}$ or not could I do the following:

First off notice $(123)=(231)$

so $G=\{1,(123),(231),(124),(142)\}$

And since inverse of permutations are just themselves written backwards,

wouldn't the inverse of (123) be (321) which is not in G , hence I can conclude it is not a subgroup? Does this work?

Comment: First chech whether $G$ is a group or NOT..

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: Yes, this would be sufficient. Since one of the requirements for a group is the existence of inverses and because you have found an element whose inverse is not contained in your proposed set, this cannot be a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Showing some subset $S_4$ (or any group) does not satisfy any of the group axioms would show that it is not a subgroup. So knowing that the inverse of $(1,2,3)$ is not in your set shows that the set is not a group.

Note that if you know you are working with a subset of a group, then the relevant axioms are closure under multiplication, and closure under inverse, or containing identity (although if closed under multiplication and inverses it must contain the identity).

Sometimes you can use other techniques, for example, if you are working with finite group you can show that the order of subgroups divide the order of the full group, although in this case you have a subset of order 4, so that does not tell you anything since $4$ divides the order of the group.

Comment: +1, but isn't the subset size $5$, problematic for numerous reasons?

Comment: @pjs36 In this case the subset is not size $5$ (if it were it definitely would be an obstruction to being a subgroup). At first glance I thought the same thing but $(123)=(231)$, so it is size $4$, that is the set is $G=\{1,(123),(124),(142)\}$

Comment: Ah, so that's what that bit in the OP was about; got it! (Shamefully I didn't even think to count the size of the subset until reading your answer!)